# Replacing &amp;quot; with &quot; for XML

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, quotation-marks

My program is a HTML parser and it saves everything into XML file. The problem is when I'm trying open a file and read the text, it gives me for example:`&amp;quot;NAME&amp;quot;`
when it should be `&quot;NAME&quot;` 
It seems that when I use `.Replace("&amp;quot;", "&quot;")` It writes &quot as &amp ; quot ; once again. How should I handle it?

Edit:

It's `<td>  "IN QUOTE" BLA BLA BLA</td>`

I do save this right here:

```
 debt.Debtor.LegalPerson.Name = nazwa;
```

While debuging, the string I get is: `&quot;IN QUOTE&quot; BLA BLA BLA`

But when I write everything into XML

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BGW_IMPORT));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, bgw);
        }

       ...
        }
        if (File.Exists(FilePath))
        {
            //XDocument existing;
            XmlDocument ex = new XmlDocument();
            XmlDocument docX = new XmlDocument();

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
            {
                //existing = XDocument.Load(fs);

                docX.LoadXml(doc.Document.ToString());
                ex.Load(fs);

                foreach (XmlNode wiersz in docX.SelectNodes("//Debt"))
                {
                    XmlNode importNode = ex.ImportNode(wiersz, true);
                    ex.DocumentElement["Debts"].AppendChild(importNode);

                }
            }

            File.Delete(FilePath);
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
            {
                ex.Save(fs);

            }...
```

At the end I get:

```
<Name>&amp;quot;IN QUOTE&amp;quot;BLA BLA BLA</Name>
```

When I want a:

```
<Name>&quot;IN QUOTE&quot;BLA BLA BLA</Name>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the original HTML, the XML being produced, the XML you want, and the code you're using?

Comment: I can't give a full example, but I edited thread, hope it helps.

Comment: Why can't you give a full example? It's not clear why you're using XmlSerializer at all...

Answer (score 0):

you first need to encode your string using 
 System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode ()

and then decode using HtmlDecode()

refer to the link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `instead of .Replace("&quot;", """)` I don't have such a replacement.
and replacing &amp with "\"" would leave me with "quot;

Comment: That's weird but it does nothing, I mean it does, but I feel like this & is again replaced by &amp ; at the end. Don't know... maybe it's some type of encoding problem?

Comment: oh yeah i remember .. it's related to System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode () and HtmlDecode()  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k(v=vs.110).aspx this link would help you.